# stumble upon type of navigation on home page (with pictures)

Tags: php, loops, slider, posts

The theme that I am using is Imbalance by wpshower.

I will provide the theme's [code](https://github.com/wpshower/imbalance) in an organized fashion.

Basically, What I am trying to do is have [my website's home page](http://s1336.beta.photobucket.com/user/jackhoff6/media/homepage1_zps3d4081a9.png.html?sort=3&o=1) function like the the two pictures below.

(blasts, only allowed to post 2 hyperlinks. You can still see the picture next to the one previously posted above)

(explanation below)

There will be 6 arrows in total on the left and right side of the page. When you reach my website, It will load up the home page from latest post's that are created(going from most recent to oldest) When the user clicks on the left/ right arrow's ( either 1st/2nd/3rd )basically there will be a "stumble effect" and the three pictures that are aligned with the closet triangle will change to a random post.

(the posts are actually featured images)

Please look at the two pictures below, they are indeed poorly drawn but it symbolizes what I am asking for on a visual level. I tried asking a question on the imbalance forum but to no response.. I have literally am not sure how to tackle this one due to my lack of experience in somewhat sophisticated php.

If anyone could help me out I would be much appreciated and reward you in a respectable fashion.

Cheers.